# Labview System Exec VI different results than command window

Tags: labview

When I try to run my executable (.exe) from the command window it works fine, but nothing happens when using the same commands in LabView's system exec VI. What do I need to change in my labview program?
[image: Command using System Exec VI]
[image: Command using command window]

I have tried calling the executable directly from the VI's command line, and have tried adjusting/deleting the working directory. I have not been able to start the .exe successfully yet.

Answer (score 3):

You use "standard input" parameter in an incorrect way. Try this:
[image: correct usage of node]